# simulate button pressed by single tap

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap

as titled, would like to tap the screen, screen will be a bit dark translucent, while the finger leaves the screen, the screen turn back to normal, which is similar as UIButton does.

In this case, I know `UIButton` is much easier, but here is **just a sample**

my codes as the following:

```
- (IBAction)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    UIView * tintView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:tintView];

    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized: {
        [tintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.25 green:.25 blue:.25 alpha:.5]];
        NSLog(@"begin");
    }
    default: {
        [tintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        NSLog(@"ended");
    }
    }
}
```

But, when tapping the screen, it won't be changed as above codes looks, although `begin` and `ended` are captured in the console.

If interchanging those codes between `case` and `default` like

```
    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized: {
        [tintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        NSLog(@"begin");
    }
    default: {
        [tintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.25 green:.25 blue:.25 alpha:.5]];
        NSLog(@"ended");
    }
    }
```

`begin` and `ended` could be shown in the console, but the screen will be darker and darker when tapping, never back to normal, clear color.

What's wrong with my codes? How to make it happen?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using the very complete button simulator from Apple, called UIButton?

Comment: `UIButton` is ok, I can handle it to realize my idea. Here is just a sample that I want to use for different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:] would be the usual way to accomplish something like this.

You'd setup your method which dismisses the darkened view separately, then reference it as the selector

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodWhichDismissesDarkView:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2]
```

call this immediately after you darken the view, and 0.2 seconds later it will fire.

To really do it right though, make sure you can gracefully handle interruptions that happen during the delay by using this:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Which will cancel the pending action when the app no longer needs to handle it.

Comment: where to put these two methods? In `viewDidLoad` or `- (IBAction)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender` ?

Comment: write the "removeTint" (or whatever you want to a call it) method separately. Then, from within your - (IBAction)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender method you would tint the view, then call [self performSelector:@selector(removeTint) withObject:nil afteDelay:0.5];

Answer (score 0):

by following @ryancumley 's hint, below is updated codes.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIView * tintView;
@synthesize tintView;

- (IBAction)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
        switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized: {
            [self.tintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.000 alpha:0.150]];
            [self performSelector:@selector(setTintView:) withObject:nil afterDelay:.25];
            NSLog(@"begin");
        }
        default: {
            break;
            NSLog(@"ended");
        }
    }
}

- (void)setTintView:(UIView *)tintView
{
    [self.tintView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.25 green:.25 blue:.25 alpha:0]];
}
```

It works finally and looks like tapping a button. But, `NSLog(@"ended")` not triggered.

Why my original can't work?

Is this updated a correct approach or workaround?

Comment: You have the NSLog(@"ended") statement within the default: portion of your switch statement. As written, it will only get triggered when the sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized.  If you want to see an NSLog of "ended" when setTintView finishes, place the log statement in the setTintView: method

Comment: Understanding from your explaination and real results from codes, `switch` sentence looks like run only **one** `case` among cases and `default`. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct, I'm not really sure that you need a switch statement here, unless you have some other functionality you're trying to accomplish. You can probably just use an  if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {//code goes here} statement instead

Comment: No problem! Have fun and keep experimenting.